# How can I find out if this is a geode without breaking it in half?

Tags: rocks, geode

I found this rock today on my property. It looks similar to another rock I saw that was said to be a civil war cannon ball, however comments below suggest that it could be a geode.

1. Are there any tests I can do *short of breaking it in half* to find out if it is a geode?
2. If I wanted to break it into two halves in a nice way (rather than smash it up into several random pieces) how might I do that?

[image: possible geode?]

Comment: it is not a cannonball(they are made of iron)

Comment: @trond hansen: It was actually quite common in some times/places to make cannonballs out of stone, though I think not in the US Civil War: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_shot

Comment: It's definitely not a cannon ball, it's not round enough. It looks very similar to some geodes I found in Oman many years ago. To  test if it is a geode, you have to break it open. Geodes are hollow inside and usually lined with pretty quartz crystals, but more rarely contain amethyst or opal.

Comment: Rock identification requests are being phased out, so I've modified your question in order to make it more likely to be on-topic, then voted to reopen. *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Comment: The best thing would be to use an angle grinder, which is a portable electric tool for cutting through hard materials  If you can't find one, try a large hacksaw. One of your neighbours will probably have one.